# How does the equation for the SpatRaster roughness index (terrain, v = "roughness") work?

Tags: r, terra

The terra package offers and describes the following terrain indices:

```
x <- terrain(x, v="roughness")
x <- terrain(x, v="TPI")
x <- terrain(x, v="TRI")
```

I am confused on how this is calculated based on the package description of roughness as "the difference between the maximum and the minimum value of a cell and its 8 surrounding cells" (Hijmans et al. 2023). How does this work for edge and corner cells? I am assuming that the calculation reduces to a cell and its 5 or 3 surrounding cells in these cases?

The ruggedness (TRI) index is described as "the mean of the absolute differences between the value of a cell and the value of its 8 surrounding cells". The following is a graphic illustration of how I envision the calculation of these indices from the description provided.

[image: cell matrix queen 8 center pixel difference - ruggedness: average of abs middle minus Q8, or roughness: middle minus Q8 not absolute difference]
Does this provide a correct interpretation of these indices?

If this interpretation is incorrect, then I am hoping someone point me in the correct direction (a reference) or explain here. I am interested in coding to calculate a slope of 16° from a DSM and an elevational difference of 1.3 m, but think that a terrain index would give a better indicator of the 1.3 m criterion for this habitat model.

```
## > 16° slope
habitat_slope_mat <- matrix(nrow = 2, ncol = 3)
habitat_slope_mat[1, ] <- c(0,16,0) # from,to = 0 absent
habitat_slope_mat[2, ] <- c(16,minmax(x)[2],1) # from,to = 1 present

habitat_slope <- classify(x, habitat_slope_mat, include.lowest=TRUE)
```

I looked at the cited references and was expecting to find the formula for this to help me think of the best way to treat the 1.3 m criterion. I have been unable to locate a written / published description that further explains the method. This paper is listed in the citations for the terrain function description:

Jones, K.H., 1998. A comparison of algorithms used to compute hill (sic) *terrain *as a property of the DEM. Computers & Geosciences 24: 315-323

The correct title for the article (DOI: 10.1016/S0098-3004(98)00032-6) is: "A comparison of algorithms used to compute hill *slope *as a property of the DEM". I cannot locate the formula for roughness in that paper and was interested in reading more on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this question is appropriate here, as you do not seem to be asking a coding question.

The manual points to [Wilson et al](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01490410701295962) (2007) for terrain indices. It also shows how you can use `focal` instead of `terrain` to compute them.

You can see for yourself what happens with small examples like this:

```
library(terra)
x <- rast(nrow=3, ncol=3, vals=c(1,2,3,1,2,1,1,2,8), ext=ext(0,1,0,1), crs="local")

as.matrix(x, wide=T)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    1    2    1
#[3,]    1    2    8

terrain(x, "roughness") |> as.matrix(wide=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  NaN  NaN  NaN
#[2,]  NaN    7  NaN
#[3,]  NaN  NaN  NaN

focal(x, w=3, fun=\(x) {max(x) - min(x)}) |> as.matrix(wide=T)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA   NA   NA
#[2,]   NA    7   NA
#[3,]   NA   NA   NA
 
terrain(x, "TRI") |> as.matrix(wide=TRUE)
#     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,]  NaN   NaN  NaN
#[2,]  NaN 1.375  NaN
#[3,]  NaN   NaN  NaN

focal(x, w=3, fun=\(x) sum(abs(x[-5]-x[5]))/8) |> as.matrix(wide=T)
#     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   NA    NA   NA
#[2,]   NA 1.375   NA
#[3,]   NA    NA   NA
```

So the edges become missing (you could do other things via focal)

Or look at the [source code](https://github.com/rspatial/terra/blob/master/src/distRaster.cpp#L3218-L3248).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure if it belonged here either, but your example includes the code I should have developed to investigate the problem. It is a direction I was working toward. Very helpful.